# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable in the output

Tags: python, dictionary

```
count = 0
temp = 0
for w in sorted(dict, key = dict.get, reverse = True):
    count +=1
    #print w, dict[w]   
    #shingles_list.append(w)    

print "the total number of %s shingles found are %s  " % (k,count)
```

i get the error TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable. It was working before and then i dont know what i did to make it stop working. can someone assist ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have potentially used `sorted` as a variable name ... and it now contains a dictionary, rather than referencing a function.